# What is difference between "Bhagvan" and "Bhagavant"?

Tags: gods

We consider Indra, Varuna, Ganesha as bhagavan. And Matsya to Kalki are bhagavan and also they are Avatar of bhagavant.

So my question is what is the difference between bhagavan and bhagavant.

I just read in Bhagavat Geeta, Bhagavant is the one who created this universe (Can you please eloberate this?), then who are bhagavan??

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  There is no such word as Bhagavant.  Bhagavan is a noun meaning God, Bhagavad is an adjective meaning "of Bhagavan", and Bhagavata is a noun meaning "devotee of Bhagavan" (usually used to mean Vaishnava).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, I am referring Bhagavant  to the supreme god who created this universe.

Comment: @laxmikant dange - As Keshav said, there is no word called bhagavant. There is bhagavantam, which also means bhagavan only. So, there is greater no bhagavant. Bhagavan means the supreme lord who possesses six infinnite opulences viz Jnana, bala,aishwarya, veerya and shakti. Also, bhagavan is an epthitet for Lord Vishnu only (refer to Vishnu purana), while other demi gods are also some times addresses as bhagavan as they all intrically related to ultimate supreme bhagavan Lord Vishnu, who is the antaryami of all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30742/discussion-between-krishna-and-anil-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

Namaste

All hindu gods (countless gods !!) often confuse average minds, when god is ONE, hinduism has numerous gods.   Gods are representative of nadis in the human body. Nadi is a sensitive neuro zone, but it is more of spiritual center.  If all these nadis are intact, then it gives raise to kundalini and other spiritual chakras.

A farmer is interested in rains, so he prays Lord Indra. A terrorized person may invoke Lord Narasimha to get instant help !!(so long he is calm & concentrating on lord).  A student may pray to Goddess Saraswati for knowledge and doing good in exams, while a qualified graduate going for job interview may pray to Lord Ganesha.

So each hindu god is represents a nadi (spiritual force center), when the mantra is recited with concentration, that nadi gets activated

Gayatri mantra is supreme and activates all nadis at a time, so it is most powerful mantra.  By reciting this single mantra, it is assumed or equivalent to all other mantras.

So in short there is no difference between terminology of bhavan and bhagavant. These are human terms, cannot transcend the gods or demi gods.

Answer (score 1):

Bhagvan and Bhagvanta words hold same meaning but Sanskrit is such a language that it's meaning is contextual. Here I am presenting point wise contextual meaning of bhagvan.
1. According to parashara Muni father of Veda vyasa bhagvan(fortunate one) roots itself from bhagyawaan which means one who has six oppulences in full namely wealth, strength, power, beauty, fame and renunciation. So at times it has a referral meaning in relation to Krishna and other Vishnu tattvas.
2. Also used for very powerful beings like demigods indra varuna Chandra etc. Please note these are just posts like prime minister of India is just a post  so any bhagyawaan person can qualify to this. However one can never take position of Vishnu tattva and Lord shiva. So Vishnu always remains the supreme Lord and others are subordinate to him.
3. Also used in context for powerful rishis who exibhit oppulence of renunciation.